# Porting Python AES encryption routies to Golang

Tags: encryption, go, cryptography, aes

I am trying to port the following Python AES file encryption routines over to Go:

```
def derive_key_and_iv(password, salt, key_length, iv_length):
    d = d_i = ''
    while len(d) < key_length + iv_length:
        d_i = md5(d_i + password + salt).digest()
        d += d_i
    return d[:key_length], d[key_length:key_length+iv_length]


def encrypt(in_file, out_file, password, key_length=32):
    bs = AES.block_size
    salt = Random.new().read(bs - len('Salted__'))
    key, iv = derive_key_and_iv(password, salt, key_length, bs)
    cipher = AES.new(key, AES.MODE_CBC, iv)
    out_file.write('Salted__' + salt)
    finished = False
    while not finished:
        chunk = in_file.read(1024 * bs)
        if len(chunk) == 0 or len(chunk) % bs != 0:
            padding_length = (bs - len(chunk) % bs) or bs
            chunk += padding_length * chr(padding_length)
            finished = True
        out_file.write(cipher.encrypt(chunk))


def decrypt(in_file, out_file, password, key_length=32):
    bs = AES.block_size
    print(bs)
    salt = in_file.read(bs)[len('Salted__'):]
    key, iv = derive_key_and_iv(password, salt, key_length, bs)
    cipher = AES.new(key, AES.MODE_CBC, iv)
    next_chunk = ''
    finished = False
    while not finished:
        chunk, next_chunk = next_chunk, cipher.decrypt(in_file.read(1024 * bs))
        if len(next_chunk) == 0:
            padding_length = ord(chunk[-1])
            chunk = chunk[:-padding_length]
            finished = True
        out_file.write(chunk)
```

I have the following Go routines coded up but I'm not quite able to get it working. I am trying to get the encryption routines working in Go for callers that call the decrypt in Python and C so I'm really only interested in figuring out how to get my Golang encryption routine working but have included all the Python bits for clarity.

My current Go routines look like this:

```
package main
import (
    "crypto/aes"
    "crypto/cipher"
    "crypto/rand"
    "encoding/base64"
    "errors"
    "fmt"
    "io"
    "log"     
    "crypto/md5"  
    "os"
    )


func pyEncrypt(password []byte, pathToInFile string, pathToOutFile string){
    bs := int(aes.BlockSize)
    salt := make([]byte, aes.BlockSize - len("Salted__")) 
    _, err := rand.Read(salt)
    if err != nil {panic(err)}

    key, iv := deriveKeyAndIV(password, salt, bs)   
    block, err := aes.NewCipher(key)
    if err != nil {panic(err)}

    cfb := cipher.NewCFBEncrypter(block, iv)

    fin, err := os.Open(pathToInFile)
    if err != nil {panic(err)}
    defer fin.Close()

    fout, err := os.Create(pathToOutFile)
    if err != nil {panic(err)}
    defer fout.Close()

    _, err = fout.Write([]byte("Salted__")) 
    if err != nil {panic(err)}
    _, err = fout.Write(salt)
    if err != nil {panic(err)}

    for true{
        ciphertext := make([]byte, 1024 *bs)
        chunk := make([]byte, 1024 * bs)
        _, err := fin.Read(chunk)
        if err == io.EOF{
        break
        }else if err != nil{
            panic(err)
        }
        cfb.XORKeyStream(ciphertext, chunk)     
        fout.Write(ciphertext)
    }
}


func deriveKeyAndIV(password []byte, salt []byte, bs int) ([]byte, []byte) {
    var digest []byte
    hash := md5.New()
    out := make([]byte, 32 + bs) //right now I'm just matching the default key size (32) from the python script so 32 represents the default from python
    for i := 0; i < 32 + bs ; i += len(digest) {
        hash.Reset()
        hash.Write(digest)
        hash.Write(password)
        hash.Write(salt)
        digest = hash.Sum(digest[:0])
        copy(out[i:], digest)
    }
    return out[:32], out[32:32+bs] //matching the default key size from Python as that is what the application uses
}

func main() {
    pwd := []byte("test123")

    pyEncrypt(pwd, "/home/chris/pt.txt", "/home/chris/genc.txt")    
}
```

Right now it runs, lol, generates an encrypted file that looks right and the Python "decrypts" without error but it generates gibberish and doesn't actually produce the clear text.  The Python routines work by stand-alone but I can't get my Golang encrypt producing output that the Python decrypt can decrypt.  I have to match the Python encryption routine for compatibility with the callers.  Do you see what I'm doing wrong in my Golang encryption routine?  Thank you so much for your assistance.

Comment: CBC != CFB check your modes

Comment: Thank you Artjom, I've updated the code and that certainly puts me in the ball park now - thank you!  I'm experimenting with trying to replicate the padding that the Python encryption routine is doing but I'm stuck with the same output now - though - thanks to you further along and on the correct playing field now.

Comment: Thank you again Artjom. I've got the padding working like the Python now (updated my example) but there is still something I'm missing/not seeing.  It seems SO close now after your feedback.

Comment: I've got it sorted now and posted the solution in my Go code - thank you so much for taking the time to look at my code and point out the CBC != CFB mode difference.  I would not have made any progress without your having pointed that out!  Please post that as an answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: Erm, what is the reason not to use [crypto/aes](https://golang.org/pkg/crypto/aes/)? The reason why I am asking is that chances are not too bad that you'll introduce a bug during porting, whereas an existing implementation likely already was checked a couple of times.

Comment: Erm, I had not seen that yet.  Thank you for the tip.  I will give that a try and as long as it is compatible with the calling Python and C then, as you said, a lot less error prone.

Comment: @MarkusWMahlberg, I've reviewed the docs - I am using the crypto/aes libraries.  I derive the key and IV the way I do to be compatible with the Python and C that are in place and will be decrypting what I encrypt.  Thank you again for the heads up to double check the docs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the working encryption routine:

```
func pyEncrypt(password string, pathToInFile string, pathToOutFile string){
    bs := int(aes.BlockSize)
    salt := make([]byte, aes.BlockSize - len("Salted__")) 
    _, err := rand.Read(salt)
    if err != nil {panic(err)}

    key, iv := deriveKeyAndIV([]byte(password), salt, bs)   
    block, err := aes.NewCipher(key)
    if err != nil {panic(err)}

    cbc := cipher.NewCBCEncrypter(block, iv)

    fin, err := os.Open(pathToInFile)
    if err != nil {panic(err)}
    defer fin.Close()

    fout, err := os.Create(pathToOutFile)
    if err != nil {panic(err)}
    defer fout.Close()

    _,err = fout.Write([]byte("Salted__"))
    if err != nil {panic(err)}
    _,err = fout.Write(salt)
    if err != nil {panic(err)}

    for true{
        chunk := make([]byte, 1024 * bs)

        n,err := fin.Read(chunk)
        if err == io.EOF{
        break
        }else if err != nil{
            panic(err)
        }

        if n == 0 || n % bs != 0 {//need to pad up to block size :bs
            paddingLength := (bs - n % bs) 
            paddingChr := []byte(string(rune(paddingLength)))
            paddingBytes := make([]byte, paddingLength)

            for i := 0; i < paddingLength; i++{
                paddingBytes[i] = paddingChr[0]
            }

            chunk = append(chunk[0:n], []byte(paddingBytes)...)
        }else{
            chunk = chunk[0:n]//no padding needed           
        }

        ciphertext := make([]byte, len(chunk))
        cbc.CryptBlocks(ciphertext,chunk)
        fout.Write(ciphertext)
    }
}
```